# Unsure on my output with regards to malloc (c)

Tags: c, arrays, malloc

What should I consider thinking about when understanding the output? Because right now my output is garbage for 20 integers and I dont know why. MY objective is to create 20 arrays with 30 integers in each one. So the final array will have integers of 19 to 48.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{

int **p;//Declaration of a pointer variable
int  i = 0, j;
int rows = 20;
int columns = 30;

    p = (int**)malloc(20 * sizeof(int)); //First "bookend" allocates space
    printf("Hello World! I have created a dynamic 20-array of 20x30 integers!\n");

if (p == NULL)
{
    printf("Failed to allocated memory!");
    exit(1);
}



for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    if (p[i] == NULL)
    {
        printf("Integers not allocated! ");
    }
    p[i] = (int**)malloc(20 * sizeof(int));
}


for (i = 0; i < 20; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < 20; j++)
    {
        if (p[j] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Integers not allocated! ");
        }
        p[i][j] = (int *)malloc(40 * sizeof(int));

    }
    printf("%d\n", p[(i+1)+j]);
}

free(p); 

return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note: `20 != 30` ... and `20 != 40`

Comment: Thank you. I'm still printing addresses. (I deleted the extra for loop)

Answer (score 0):

I hope I got your question right...

What you are getting isn't exactly garbase...  When doing `p[i][j] = (int *)malloc(40 * sizeof(int));` you are just allocating one more array with 40 elements and putting it's address in `p[i][j]`... So when you try to print `p[(i+1)+j]` you are printing the address of that 40 elements array you malloc'd.

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues with your code:

- For the initial allocation, each element is an `int *`, so you need `20 * sizeof(int *)`, not `20 * sizeof(int)`.
- Any space allocated by `malloc` is uninitialized, so attempting to read it is undefined behavior.  If on the other hand you use `calloc`, that initializes the allocated memory to all 0.
- You go through an extra set of loops attempting to allocate another array to each `int` location.  If you were trying to create a 3D array (and defined `p` as `int ***`) that would work, but not for a 2D array.
- Don't cast the return value of malloc, as that can mask subtle bugs.

If you want to dynamically allocate a 20 X 30 array of `int`, you do it like this:

```
// first allocate 20 int*
int **p = malloc(20 * sizeof(int *));
if (p == NULL) {
    perror("malloc failed");
    exit(1);
}

int i;
for (i=0;i<30;i++) {
    // for each row, allocate 30 int
    p[i] = malloc(30 * sizeof(int));
    if (p[i] == NULL) {
        perror("malloc failed");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

Note that this doesn't set any values in the 2D array, it just allocates the memory for it.